# efficiency of correlated queries

Tags: sql

just a question on the efficiency of correlated queries.
Let's say I want to write an outer query against an instance of the OrderValues view called O1; in the SELECT list, divide the current value by the result of a correlated subquery that returns the total value from a second instance of OrderValues called O2 for the current customer. Here’s the complete solution query.

```
SELECT orderid, custid, val,
 CAST(100. * val / (SELECT SUM(O2.val)
 FROM Sales.OrderValues AS O2
 WHERE O2.custid = O1.custid)
 AS NUMERIC(5,2)) AS pct
FROM Sales.OrderValues AS O1
ORDER BY custid, orderid;
```

```
orderid custid val pct
----------- ----------- ---------- ------
10643 1 814.50 19.06
10692 1 878.00 20.55
10702 1 330.00 7.72
10835 1 845.80 19.79
10952 1 471.20 11.03
11011 1 933.50 21.85
10308 2 88.80 6.33
10625 2 479.75 34.20
10759 2 320.00 22.81
10926 2 514.40 36.67
```

but for the query `SELECT SUM(O2.val) FROM Sales.OrderValues AS O2 WHERE O2.custid = O1.custid`, it only needs to be executed once for each custid, for example, the first row with custoid of 1, after the first row, we alread have the total sales for custid 1 then for the second row, structure of correlated query seems to execute the inner query again every time regardless of possible duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a correlated subquery and it can be efficient -- particularly with the right indexes.

But this is better written using window functions:

```
SELECT orderid, custid, val,
       CAST(100. * val / SUM(SUM(O2.val)) OVER (PARTITION BY custid)  AS NUMERIC(5,2)) AS pct
FROM Sales.OrderValues ov
ORDER BY custid, orderid;
```